# Server's caching wrong image/index.html

Tags: html, web, caching, bootstrap-4

I have a logo that changed, however both my Xampp server AND domain server are caching old/incorrect logo.

What I have in index file:

```
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="assets/images/logo3.png" alt="Logo">
                </a>
```

What loads in browser:

[image]

one thing I have noticed is that it only happens when I scroll down the page and navbar turns into a sticky.

I have tried Ctrl+F5.

Also added

```
   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

but nothing seems to help.

How can I force it to update/clear?

Answer (score 0):

Try `CTRL+SHIFT+F5` or `CTRL+SHIFT+R`

[image]

Comment: @Wizy can you show your html and folder directory?